# meaning of different Jbutton declration

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton

What is the difference in the   declarations of buttons given below ?

```
1. JButton button = (JButton)value;
2. JButton button = new JButton("BUTTON NAME);
```

Comment: `new JButton("BUTTON NAME")`: Please close the quotes for string declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> JButton button = (JButton)value;

Cases an arbitrary object from one type to `JButton`.  You see this in things like `ActionListener`s where the `ActionEvent` only supplies a reference to an `Object` as the source of the event, for example.

> JButton button = new JButton("BUTTON NAME);

Creates a new instance of `JButton`

Comment: The reason I am asking is that in my program I have to add JButtons in one column of Jtable where all the other values are fetched from database. So, the link I referred to had used the values to be filled in the code itself. Hence the used JButton button = (JButton)value; But I got error on doing so, hence instead of this line I wrote JButton button = new JButton("BUTTON NAME); and on doing this the buttons got displayed. But now I seem to use this object variable value somewhere else too in my code. So can you tell me how to to so ?

Comment: Not without more context, consider updating your question and provide an actual [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) this will reduce the guess work and provide responses to your question

Comment: I've now updated my problem. Kindly help me providing a fix !

Comment: :[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23804025/need-to-access-the-value-of-other-column-in-jtable-when-jbutton-is-clicked-jbu)

Answer (score 1):

```
JButton button = (JButton)value;
```

This is called type casting. see the below example:

```
byte a = 1;
byte b = 2;
byte c = a + b;  // this will give compile error    
byte c = (byte)(a + b); // compiles ok
```

the cast operator (type) is used to convert values from one type to another or to change an object reference to a compatible type.

```
JButton button = new JButton("BUTTON NAME);
```

This is normal declration of the object, which creates a new button object.